# SQL Server looping through inside stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, loops

I have a C# windows application which is related to products. In my application we fetch the date when the product is added to the inventory. Based on the `AddDate` of the product, we get the age of the product in months.

Let's say the age of a product is 25 months.

```
int Age = 25;

for(int i = Age; i >=0; i --)
{
    var result = GetProductData(DateTime.Now.AddMonth(0-i));
}
```

The `GetProductData()` method calls a stored procedure, so if the age of the product is 25 months, the stored procedure gets called 25 times.

In the stored procedure, we extract the month and year part from the `DateTime` and store those bits into 2 separate variables. This is how it is currently

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetProductData
     @AppId INT,
    @Date DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Month INT
    DECLARE @Year INT
    DECLARE @ProductInstall INT

    SELECT @Month = SELECT DATEPART(m, @Date)
    SELECT @Year = SELECT YEAR(@Date)

    SELECT @ProductInstall = (SUM(P.[AutoInstalls]) + SUM(P.[ITInstalls]))
    FROM dbo.[ProductInstalls] P 
    INNER JOIN [User] U ON U.[UserId] = P.[UserId] 
    WHERE LicenseRequired = 1 
      AND DATEPART(m, P.[InstallDate]) = @month 
      AND DATEPART(year, P.[InstallDate]) = @Year

    SELECT 
        AVG(A.[TotalRequests] - A.[TotalInstalls]) * 100 AS [ProductAverage], 
        @ProductInstall, @Month/@Year 
    FROM 
        dbo.[ApplicationInstalls]
    /*There are few more joins and some business logic after this */
    WHERE 
        DATEPART(m, A.[InstallDate]) = @Month 
        AND DATEPART(year, A.[InstallDate]) = @Year
END
```

Now instead of calling the stored procedure as many times as the age of product/application, I want to do it in a single request as I already have the date the application/product was added to the inventory

```
DECLARE @ProductAddDate
DECLARE @ProductAge
SELECT @ProductAddDate = [DateAdded] FROM dbo.[Application] WHERE [AppId] = @AppId
SELECT @ProductAge = DATEDIFF(DAY, @ProductAddDate, GETDATE())/30
```

Now with the product age I have, I want to loop through the below logic for every month.

```
 SELECT 
     @ProductInstall = (SUM(P.[AutoInstalls]) + SUM(P.[ITInstalls]))
 FROM 
     dbo.[ProductInstalls] P 
 INNER JOIN
     [User] U ON U.[UserId] = P.[UserId] 
 WHERE 
     LicenseRequired = 1 
     AND DATEPART(m, P.[InstallDate]) = @month 
     AND DATEPART(year, P.[InstallDate]) = @Year

 SELECT 
     AVG(A.[TotalRequests] - A.[TotalInstalls]) * 100 AS [ProductAverage], @ProductInstall, 
     @Month/@Year 
 FROM 
     dbo.[ApplicationInstalls]
     /*There are few more joins and some business logic after this */
 WHERE 
     DATEPART(m, A.[InstallDate]) = @Month 
     AND DATEPART(year, A.[InstallDate]) = @Year
```

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft and *should not* be used for User Stored Procedures. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: corrected it, appreciate your input.

Comment: I would create two stored procedures.  One that gets the monthly results and a second one that returns a range of months (calling first stored procedure).  the c# will call the second procedure to get all the monthly totals.

Comment: so the 2nd procedure will be calling stored the 1st stored procedure multiple times based on the age of product did i get it right ? If the Age of product is 10 then 10 times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your core logic really represents 'application' data, or product data, but I'll keep the proc name as 'getProductData'.  Here's what it does:

- First, in the 'monthYears' CTE, I get the product-add-date for the application and create month and year bins that spread from the add date to the present date.  This is the only 'looping' I do.  Otherwise, the healthier approach is to use set-theoretical operations available in SQL Server, which are much more efficient.
- Then, in the 'productInstalls' CTE, I take your logic, omit the month and year filters, and instead group by month and year to get them all at once.
- I do the same for your application installs logic in the 'applicationInstalls' CTE.
- Finally, I join it all together by year and month in the core query.

Here's the code:

```
create procedure getProductData
    @AppId int 
as 

declare @ProductAddDate date = (
    select  dateAdded 
    from    [application] 
    where   appId = @AppId
);

with

    monthYears as (

        select      mo = datepart(m, @productAddDate),
                    yr = datepart(year, @productAddDate),
                    i = 0

        union all
        select      mo = datepart(m, dateAdd(m, i+1, @productAddDate)),
                    yr = datepart(year, dateAdd(m, i+1, @productAddDate)),
                    i = i+1
        from        monthYears
        where       datepart(m, dateAdd(m, i+1, @productAddDate)) <= datepart(m, getdate())
        and         datepart(year, dateAdd(m, i+1, @productAddDate)) <= datepart(year, getdate())
                
    ),

    productInstalls as (

        select      mo = datepart(m, p.installDate), 
                    yr = datepart(year, p.installDate), 
                    ProductInstall = sum(p.autoinstalls) + sum(p.itinstalls)
        from        productInstalls p 
        join        [user] u on u.userId = p.userId 
        where       licenseRequired = 1 
        group by    datepart(m, p.installDate),
                    datepart(year, p.installDate)

    ),

    applicationInstalls as (

        select      mo = datepart(m, a.installDate), 
                    yr = datepart(year, a.installDate), 
                    ProductAverage = avg(a.totalRequests - a.totalInstalls) * 100
        from        applicationInstalls a
        group by    datepart(m, p.installDate),
                    datepart(year, p.InstallDate)

    )

    select      my.yr,
                my.mo,
                ProductAverage = isnull(a.ProductAverage, 0),
                ProductInstall = isnull(p.ProductInstall, 0)
    from        monthYears my
    left join   applicationInstalls a on my.yr = a.yr and my.mo = a.mo
    left join   productInstalls p on my.yr = p.yr and my.mo = p.mo;
```

When you get this in C#, it will be as a collection.  Most likely it will be output as a DataTable or your business layer might output it as an IEnumerable or List of some type.  So your looping, if necessary, will then occur in the C# code, not the SQL code.

Something like:

```
int appId = 0;  // or whatever

foreach(var productDatum in GetProductData(appId)) {
    // do something with productDatum
}
```

Comment: This is awesome and it worked like a charm, Thanks a Ton.

Comment: can this be modified a bit, instead of getting all the data i need only recent 6 months, if the product got added on Jan 2020 its age is 12 months but i just need to get recent 6 months.. If the product age is 3 months then only 3 months

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an "Answer" per se, but I do have an idea that might be worth looking deeper into. In SQL Server, there is the concept of Window Functions. [Itsak Ben-Gan wrote a book on it a few years back](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135861446), but you can find it by Googling - here is [one site](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/).

The con here is you have to start thinking differently to program this way. The pro is, where applicable, no recursion. The window flows down through the table on a single scan gathering the aggregates as it goes down. A few years back, I used this to determine scheduling conflicts in a large scale app, reducing time to return results from 10 - 20 seconds to about .5 seconds. You may not require this performance bump, but if you can figure out how to apply to your problem, you avoid a lot of table (or index) scans.